# FlipView rendering problems in windows 8.1 application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, flipview

I'm creating Windows store application (target 8.1, WPF and C#) and I'm using FlipView control for navigation between pages with 24 pictures of some articles thumbnails. When I have small count of the pages, everything goes quite smooth and nice. But in the case of more pages sometimes it is lagging and it is not very comfortable for user.

There is a part of my FlipView declaration :

```
<FlipView Name="FlipView" ItemsSource="{Binding ArticlesPages}" 
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedPageIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

One thing that should boost performance and rendering speed is **VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode** but in my opinion it behaves similarly.

Do you have any idea how to boost FlipView performance? I tried it on tablet and on laptop with i5 processor and with big amount of RAM but it is still not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If the CPU/Memory expensive part you have is Image/Thumbnail loading you can look at my FlipViewBehavior - [ImageExtensions library](https://github.com/thefex/ImageExtensions/blob/development/ImageExtensions/Behaviors/FlipViewMemoryEfficientLazyImageLoad.cs). It's not yet production-ready state (although it works - documentation is almost non existent atm.) - but I plan to merge it into winrt xaml toolkit soon ( when cleaned up, in ~month ). The main idea is: load asynchronously, stop loading items that are too far from current item, clear memory, dispose items which aren't visible (keep at most three loaded pictures in memory) - it is achieved with hand-written `CircularQueue` in link above. I use it to display a lot of filtered images on windows phone and it works pretty well.

`VirtualizationPanel` sure gives you virtualization - but it means that there will be few `FlipViewItems` containers (for instance if you got `ItemsSource` with 1000 items there will be for instance ~10-15 UI container panels which would be reused if Recycling mode is enabled). However if you load any memory-expensive resources for your `ItemsSource` - it will occupy memory anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think please that it is caused by Image loading? Because it looks that when I go to another page, images are already loaded. It looks like WPF has problem to render pages during swiping between them. Another point is that I have 24 pictures on one page. Is your ImageExtensions library appropriate for my case as well please?

Comment: It would be great if you could show the way you load images so I could tell help you better. Looks like all your images are loaded on page initialization (low performance). Btw. do you use WPF or WinRT ?

Comment: I only set image url path on the server. Here is my code how I display images https://gist.github.com/cechovsky/aadcf97f9f445742608a . But in my opinion, loading of pictures is performed well. I have issue only with swiping between pages. Pictures are already loaded but swiping is not smooth. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thats pretty weird - that shouldn't have big impact on performance, what else are you doing on page load (navigation)?